# click on cookie popups using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to web **scraping**. For a little project i decided to try and log into instagram automatically. I am using chrome web driver to open the page and selenium to process it. i can get selenium to open Instagram but on instagram there is a cookie popup that i can't seem to automate a click for. I keep getting a error. what i want to do is just to pick the accept all.

my code is:

```
#Selenium imports here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

#Other imports here
import os
#import wget

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/kitchensink/Desktop/instab/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

Accept_all = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Accept All)]"))).click()
```

There error that i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kitchensink/PycharmProjects/instapost/main3.py", line 15, in <module>
    Accept_all = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Accept All)]"))).click()
  File "/Users/kitchensink/.local/share/virtualenvs/kitchensink-UJdjJQi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: P.S : I am not downvoting your questions in case if you are wondering.  I do not do this cheap things. There were already 3 downvotes on your question, I can not downvote it right 3 times ?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion here, good spot with the coma it was good mistake that you noticed. It didn't solve the issue on my side, which was the wrong xpath. Using the full path below worked but that coma was missing too. so it was a blend of your answer and the below answer. thanks for the help on it.

Comment: I do not mind you accepted the below answer. It's okay if that work for you. but always acknowledge when some put efforts on your question. I had downvoted this question, but will take it back cause we all are learning here :)

Comment: 100% agree, we are all here for a bit of learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as an xpath: `/html[@class='js not-logged-in client-root js-focus-visible sDN5V']/body/div[@class='RnEpo Yx5HN      _4Yzd2']/div[@class='pbNvD    FrS-d  gD9tr ']/div[@class='_1XyCr ']/button[@class='aOOlW  bIiDR  ']`

So your code would look like:

```
#Selenium imports here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

#Other imports here
import os
#import wget

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

Accept_all = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[@class='js not-logged-in client-root js-focus-visible sDN5V']/body/div[@class='RnEpo Yx5HN      _4Yzd2']/div[@class='pbNvD    FrS-d  gD9tr ']/div[@class='_1XyCr ']/button[@class='aOOlW  bIiDR  ']"))).click()
```

EDIT: I tried it and it works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

See you have a issue with **xpath** here : (Your xpath does not contain `'` at the end) you are using this

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Accept All)]
```

but one should use this instead :

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Accept All')]
```